# How to invoke method without any directives in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 *API's*

1. API 1 `app.get('/all-products')` - It gets the list of products from the database.
2. API 2 'app.get('/image:_id')' - gets images based on *product id*.

Individually both the *APIs* are working, but the problem is:

I want to display one image per product.

So I thought, to pass *product id* in the method, which will return image data, and I can show that image for every product.

But according to my knowledge, there is no way to do this without *Angular Events*.

*Angular controller:*

```
    $http.get('/products/listProducts').then(function (res) {
                $scope.products = res.data;
                $scope.getImageById(id);//to get image for every image
              });
```

How can I do this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

In angularjs, The response of your $http(...) call is a **`promise`**. So you can use **`$q.all`** to wait for an array of images to complete.

```
$scope.updateAllImages = function(){
    $scope.data = null ;  
    var promises = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.products,function(id,key){
      promises.push($scope.getImage(id));
    });
    $q.all(promises).then(function success(data){
      console.log($scope.data);  
    }, function failure(err){
      // Can handle this is we want
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but how can I pass id from in `$scope.getImageById(id)`? `listProducts` API will have array of data i.e list of products, so for each product, I want to call a method that will get image.

Comment: Hmm, I have, but I am calling ` $scope.getProducts` service in *init method* to get list of products.

Comment: that does not matter, this is the concept

Comment: my code is just a sample, you might have to alter a bit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159288/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: Hi, I am able to get images, but it's showing the same image for every product.
`<section class="section" ng-repeat="product in products">
 <div class="view overlay hm-white-slight">
                                                <img class="thumb" ng-src="{{ imageData.imagePaths[0]}}" height="500" width="500">`